# flash app accessing webservice; "security error accessing url". crossdomain in place

Tags: web-services, flash, cross-domain

I have a Flash app on SSL **Internet** Domain1 and web services on non-SSL **Intranet** Domain2. Firewall port 80 is open between them. A Crossdomain file is in place on Domain2.

`<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/> 
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/> 
</cross-domain-policy>`

I think that is pretty wide open.

I can access web services on Domain2 directly from Domain1 no errors.

When flash app loads, Fiddler shows WSDL is loaded. An Init function calls the web service to load a combobox.  I never see that call in Fiddler.

Everything works fine on my dev instance, which is all on Domain2.

I'm 98% sure that its a Crossdomain issue, but 2% reserved for unknowns. I have looked at Crossdomain posts on many forums for weeks (really! it's a side project) and tried many different changes. Nothing has made any difference.

Any suggestions are hugely appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`<allow-access-from>` and `<allow-http-request-headers-from>` have a not well know attribute `secure`.
This attribute is there specifically to indicate if we authorize secure connections from an insecure domain (ie https from http); and its true by default (connection refused).

try with this crossdomain, it may solve your issue.

```
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```